# Writing an Alternate_Case function in c?

Tags: c

I wrote this function which, though it didn't work:

```
char *alternateCase (char *string)
{
  while (*string)
  {
    if (islower(*string)) *string = toupper(*string); 
    else if (isupper(*string)) *string = tolower(*string); 
    string++;
  }
  return string; 
}
```

So, i tried to add a pointer to the string variable and it worked, the second function was as follows:

```
char *alternateCase (char *string)
{
  char *ptr= string;
  while (*ptr)
  {
    if (islower(*ptr)) *ptr = toupper(*ptr); 
    else if (isupper(*ptr)) *ptr = tolower(*ptr); 
    ptr++;
  }
  return string; 
}
```

I didn't fully understand why the first function didn't work, while the second worked. It seems to me that they are identical!
Why the second is right, and the first is wrong?

Comment: The second function returns a pointer to the _beginning_ of the string, but the first one returns a pointer to the _end_ of the string (because you change `string` in the first function).

Comment: Thank you, that worked, i tried to add this after the while loop`while(n--){
    string--;
  }` where n is `strlen(string)` and its worked.

Comment: Hint: try to use `for()` loops instead of `while()`. the trailing `string++;` inside the loop can be a source of errors (think: break/continue)

Comment: Yes,I was just trying to write the function without the use of any index variables, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save pointer to the beginning of the string. In the first example you are changing pointer you received as function argument. So, you need to keep original pointer and use temporary pointer `*ptr` as in the second example.

Alternatively, you can use the first example, but you should then save string length

```
int length = strlen(string);
```

and then

```
return (char*)(string - length);
```

Comment: It should be `return (char*) (string-length);`

Comment: @MuhammadEbeid. Yes, sorry. Your while loop is a little bit weird, so it was confusing.

Comment: Is this a bad practice? how is it weird?

Comment: @MuhammadEbeid. No, it is not a bad practice, but I just often use `for` loops for problems like this one. But you can use any method and any loop you want.

Comment: I also often use `for` loops, but i was trying not to use any index variables.

Answer (score 1):

the reason the first posted example code does not work is because of these two lines.

```
string++;
and 
return string;
```

when the while loop exits, the pointer `string` is pointing at the NUL byte that terminates the input parameter string.

Returning that modified pointer results in the caller receiving a pointer to a NUL byte.  Not what is needed.